# StartActivityForResult with remote image

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-glide, android-bitmap

I've basically this code:

```
Glide.with(activity)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(url)
    .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(BUNDLE_KEY_RESULT, resource);
            activity.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            activity.finish();
            return true;
        }
    }
).submit());
```

I've two problems:

1. The activity is not finishing.
2. I receive in console the following error:

   FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1638672)

How can I solve? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Send the URL back. Do not attempt to send the bitmap back. Have the other activity obtain the image from Glide. Or, better yet, combine these two activities into one (e.g., use fragments).

Comment: I'm already using fragments, what about the Activity not finishing?

Comment: "I'm already using fragments" -- not in this code. "what about the Activity not finishing?" -- my guess is that it is tied to the "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION".

Comment: activity is an alias for getActivity(), I'm inside a fragment.

Comment: "I'm inside a fragment" -- you apparently used `startActivityForResult()` to bring up the current activity (and fragment), and you are using `setResult()` to try to send data back to that previous activity. You could remove all of that and have just one activity with multiple fragments.

Comment: Ok, problem is that the "activity 1" business logic is already quite complex...I was hoping that was easier to get a bitmap back. If I fuse the two activity, how can I get the image back in other fragment?

Comment: "I was hoping that was easier to get a bitmap back" -- it would be trivial for you to pass the `Uri` back and move your Glide code into the other activity. "how can I get the image back in other fragment?" -- modern Android development would have you use a shared `ViewModel`, perhaps with a `LiveData` for getting the `Uri` from one fragment to another. Your code that needs to display the bitmap is where you should be using Glide (e.g., to fill in an `ImageView`).

Answer (score -1):

This error because of you are trying to send Bitmap object, the size of the data matters while communicating with activities.You can use URI, or a data model class.

```
private Uri getImageUri(Context context, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

getImageUri method will return the uri of bitmap , now you can share it through Intent

Comment: Ok so basically I've to Save the image locally. Why the Activity is not finishing?

Comment: You can finish the activity from onActivityResult() method.

Comment: That's not possibile, because it's another activity.

Comment: Which activity you want to finish?